# backbone.js passing extra data along with events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using backbone.js, when a collection's [remove method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove) is called a "remove" event is fired.

1. How can I extend this "remove" event to pass extra data, such as certain attributes of the particular model being removed?
2. How can I bind to the "remove" event triggered by a specific model, specified by id or cid?

I suppose any solution would also be applicable for the "change" event? Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you basically have a bunch of views bound to models in a collection?  If so then I guess you would be feeding each model from a collection to its view and in that view you would be binding to the 'remove' event.

Comment: @Bill thanks I was wondering whether it was possible to arbitrarily bind to the change or remove events by cid. eg `.bind("c4change", function(){})` where c4 is the cid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're removing a model from a collection, you shouldn't need that model anymore.  I guess I'm missing the point of extending remove to do more than just remove something.

When you call remove on a collection, you pass the model or an array of models in the collection to the remove function.  I would recommend doing any last minute work you need with those models just before you call the remove function on your collection.  At that point you should have all the models and their attributes that you plan on removing.

To bind to the change event of a specific model you just need to get the model you want from the collection and bind to that:

```
var myModel = myCollection.get(id); //using the id of the model
```

or

```
var myModel = myCollection.getByCid(cid); //using the cid of the model
```

Now bind to that model:

```
myModel.bind("change", function() {
    //do something
});
```

or, bind change to all the models in a collection:

```
myCollection.bind("change", function(model) {
    //do something, model is the model that triggered the change event
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ryanmarc for the response. I have other elements on the page that reference the model-to-be-removed, so I'd like that model to notify those other elements so that they can unreference it and do some other processing. I guess this can be done right before removal as you say, but I was wondering whether it would be cleaner or more efficient to pass those model's attributes along with the remove event itself, since the event is called anyways.

Comment: To me, it seems as though it would be cleaner to make your calls and pass the model to be removed to the appropriate places separate of the remove method rather than extend the remove to do more.  However, if you want to override the remove function copy it out of the backbone source (under collection) and paste it into where you extend your collection.  When you call remove on that collection it will use your function rather than the one in the backbone source.